# Pycharm debugger shows the: "Variables are not available" message

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am new to debugging. I simply want to see how the variables change as I run the program. I want to see what my program does and how.

But when I try to run the debugger, it shows the message: "Variables are not available":

[image]

Comment: Because you need to set breakpoint, and when you hit it, you will see. You need to read [PyCharm debugger guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/debugging.html)

Comment: @vishes_shell 

Alright, i did that. But where do i need to put the breaking point? At the begin? Ending? And when i do the debug step by step, it opens for example: "Parsy.py", "codecs.py". And then it stops debugging?

Comment: You put breakpoint where you want to know whats going on. You can track code to the bottom(core of python or whatever python libraries)

Answer (score 4):

1. Position the cursor on a line in your code where you are interested to see your variables.
2. Press Ctrl-F8 to toggle a breakpoint.
3. Debug your code.